# Add "tf edit" in Context Menu

Tags: team-foundation-server

Quite often I need to edit files tracked in tfs (outside of visual studio). I want be able to right-click the file and select "tf edit".

What's the reg key to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Check here
http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/

in that article of "howtogeek.com" show you how to add any application to windows explorer's context menu.

Answer (score 0):

you can download the TFS powertools, this will add a whole host of TFS functionality to the Explorer context menu.

You should download the version that corresponds to the version of TFS that you are using. i.e. if you're using TFS 2010, download the 2010 powertools.